# Can we retract active answer flags?

Tags: feature-request, flags

I've flagged many posts for `link-only answer` when the user posts only a link with no explanation (e.g., to documentation). However, some users return after the fact (I've seen 3-4 hour delays in the past) to add some example code. If my flag still says "active," as in it hasn't been reviewed yet, shouldn't I be able to delete it?

Comment: There is no "link-only answer" flag.

Comment: Tons of highly upvoted similar requests. And yet.......